# How to add the attribute `preserveAspectRatio` to Highchart svg

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I need to add this attribute to the svg created by Highchart to keep them with the right alignment.

But I can't find it on the [Highchart api](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts) and I really need to add this.

Someone know how to do it ? Or maybe I can do a trick with adding it by my JavaScript ? (it would be bad...)

http://sendvid.com/gcb4pq9r here you can see why I need this attribute (no download, just a online player)

[EDIT] I really need someone who know how I can use `chart.attr()` ! It returns me that it's not a function but [here they do this on a chart](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Element.attr) and if I can do it my problem is resolved !!!

```
nameChart = Highcharts.chart(currentContainer.idChartMem, {
          title: {
                text: 'Memory usage of ' + currentContainer.nameContainer,
                style: {
                   color: '#3F7EF2',
                   fontSize: '15px'
                },
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'usage'
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        var usage = this.value;
                        if ((usage >= 1048576) && (usage < 1073741824)) {
                            return (usage / 1048576).toFixed(2) + "MB";
                        } else if (usage >= 1073741824) {
                            return (usage / 1073741824).toFixed(2) + "GB";
                        } else {
                            return usage + "KB";
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>';
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'line',
                name: 'memory usage',
                data: []
            }],
        });
        nameChart.setSize(null,250);
        console.log("before chart.attr({})");
        console.log(nameChart);
        nameChart.attr({preserveAspectRatio:'xMinYMin'});
        console.log("after chart.attr({})");
```

*No panics because I create my chart with currentContainer and things like this because it works, it create my chart*

I created an [issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6306)

Comment: hope it helps: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/how-to-set-options

Comment: @ZiTAL not really because I can't find `preserveAspectRatio` on the API despite it's an attribute for svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the instructions of TorsteinHonsi I did that:

```
nameChart.renderer.boxWrapper.attr({ preserveAspectRatio: 'xMinYMin' });
```